# I need to find a way to cache jdk instalation in gitlab pipeline

Tags: java, android, caching, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am running a GitLab pipeline for testing and building an Android app.

Here is my current `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: fabernovel/android:api-33-v1.7.0

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - beta

cache:
  key:
    files:
      - Gemfile.lock
  paths:
    - vendor/bundle

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
  - jenv add /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
  - jenv global 17.0
  - bundle check --path vendor/bundle || bundle install --path vendor/bundle --jobs $(nproc)

test:
  image: fabernovel/android:api-33-v1.7.0
  tags:
    - docker-ansible
  stage: test
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
    paths:
      - cache/caches/
      - cache/notifications/
      - cache/wrapper/

  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane test

build:
  image: fabernovel/android:api-33-v1.7.0
  tags:
    - docker-ansible
  stage: build
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
    paths:
      - cache/caches/
      - cache/notifications/
      - cache/wrapper/
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './'
  script:
    - apt update -y && apt install -y curl
    - curl -s https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer | bash
    - bundle exec fastlane build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab

beta:
  image: fabernovel/android:api-33-v1.7.0
  tags:
    - docker-ansible
  stage: beta
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane beta
  when: manual
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    refs:
      - main
```

Currently, it is working fine, but is very slow because every time I run it jdk is installed for every stage again. I can't find a valid way to cache to skip that part in the next build.
Also if there is any other way to speed up or cache, suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: if there are no frequent changes. U can create a custom base image with whatever u need and use that for the job

Comment: That would be great, but I don't have access to the server where GitLab and GitLab-runners are running.

Comment: u can push a image to dockerhub and use it from there

Comment: Also, during my research, I came across a statement from a GitLab developer where he says that it is not possible to cache anything outside the repository scope.

Comment: @JosipMaričević Yes, which is why caching an image in a container registry remains the most effective way to bypass the repetitive JDK installation.

Comment: Perhaps it would be even better if I had a dedicated runner just for this project, with everything necessary pre-installed on it so that I don't have to pull the docker image every time, right?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments, the use of a custom Docker image to encapsulate the necessary environment for your jobs should be helpful.
If you do not have direct access to the server where GitLab and GitLab runners are running, you can push a custom Docker image to a publicly accessible Docker registry like [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

Create a `Dockerfile` with the necessary JDK installation and any other dependencies you require:

```
FROM fabernovel/android:api-33-v1.7.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
```

And build your Docker image locally:

```bash
docker build -t your-username/your-image-name:your-tag .
```

Then push the custom docker image to Docker Hub**:

```bash
docker login --username=your-username
docker push your-username/your-image-name:your-tag
```

Modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to use the custom Docker image you pushed to Docker Hub:

```yaml
image: your-username/your-image-name:your-tag

# Rest of your workflow
```

Having a custom Docker image with the JDK pre-installed should significantly speed up your GitLab pipeline runs as it will no longer need to install the JDK in every run.

Comment: I would never say that it is so easy to upload a new image to the docker hub. I would never say that it is so easy to upload a new image to the docker hub. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JosipMaričević True. Do you have access to any other docker registries in your environment? A [GitLab Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/) maybe?

Comment: I don't know, is there a way to check it?

Comment: @JosipMaričević Yes, by giving more information about your development environment. Are you using a self-managed on-premise GitLab instance, or gitlab.com? Which version of GitLab are you using? Can you check if the [GitLab Container Registry ](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html) is enabled?

Comment: I am working on clients gitlab which is self-hosted on their server. And I just have access to Gitlab pipelines in the CI/CD section of the repository. Also, I am using one of their shared GitLab runners from other projects.

Comment: @JosipMaričević So the admins for that GitLab instance can tell you if the registry is set up.